# How to set use execl as root to start application as user?

Tags: c, linux

I am using execl on a C application that is started by root. The goal of the execl is to open another application as a user the application knows beforehand.

Here is the code:

```
pid = fork();
if (pid == 0) {
    sprintf(Cmd, "user1 -c '/usr/bin/iceweasel %s'", url);
    execl("/bin/su", "/bin/su", Cmd, NULL);
    //command is /bin/su user1 -c '/usr/bin/iceweasel <url>'
    exit(0);
}
```

The application seems to hang on execution of execl. It's probably expecting a password but running this on shell does not encounter any issue. For my needs, I need to be able to get the process ID of iceweasel in order to be able to control it.

Answer (score 2):

Use `setuid()` or `seteuid()` functions that let you change effective and/or real uids of the current process. In your case you should change it in between `fork()` and `exec()`.

You also have the same for group ids management : `setgid()` and `setegid()`.